# How can I submit a form every 10 seconds in React if it has events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, use-effect

So basically I have some input fields and I collect the data from a form submit ,but I have to click a button or to hit enter to submit the form. What I want is to submit the form every 10 seconds , so I tried to create a interval in a useEffect but it gives me an error , because e is not defined , yeah I have passed an event to the function

```js
 const handleDataChange = useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setUserData({
      ["job"] : e.target.elements.job.value ? e.target.elements.job.value : "",
      ["fName"] : e.target.elements.fName.value ? e.target.elements.fName.value : "",
      ["lName"] : e.target.elements.lName.value ? e.target.elements.lName.value : "",
      ["email"] : e.target.elements.email.value ? e.target.elements.email.value : "",
      ["phone"] : e.target.elements.phone.value ? e.target.elements.phone.value : "",
      ["country"] : e.target.elements.country.value ? e.target.elements.country.value : "",
      ["city"] : e.target.elements.city.value ? e.target.elements.city.value : "",
      ["pcode"] : e.target.elements.pcode.value ? e.target.elements.pcode.value : "",
      ["birth"] : e.target.elements.birth.value ? e.target.elements.birth.value : "",
      ["summary"]: summary ? summary : "",
      fireEmployment,
      fireEducation,
      fireLinks,
      fireSkills,
      fireLanguages
    })
  })
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      handleDataChange()
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [handleDataChange]);
<form className="user__infoTop" onSubmit={e => handleDataChange(e)}>
          <h1>Personal Details</h1>
          <div className="user__infoRow">
            <TextField variant="filled" type="text" label="Job Title" name="job" />
            <div className="photo">
              <label htmlFor="upload-photo">
                <Avatar src={img} alt="avatar" />
                <span>
                  Upload <CloudUploadIcon />
                </span>
              </label>
              <input
                type="file"
                id="upload-photo"
                hidden
                onChange={onFileChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="user__infoRow">
            <TextField variant="filled" type="text" label="First Name" name="fname" />
            <TextField variant="filled" type="text" label="Last Name" name="lname" />
          </div>
          <div className="user__infoRow">
            <TextField variant="filled" type="email" label="email" name="email" />
            <TextField variant="filled" type="text" label="Phone number" name="phone" />
          </div>
          <div className="user__infoRow">
            <TextField variant="filled" type="text" label="Country" name="country" />
            <TextField variant="filled" type="text" label="City" name="city" />
          </div>
          </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: this is happening when called from the setinterval function because you are not passing any argument to the handleDataChange function

Comment: ok so how can I pass the event into the setInterval function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to do this, I created a submit button and gave it display: none and then from an useEffect function I created an interval that will click that button every 10 seconds.
Here is the code :

```js
   useEffect(() => {
     const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const formSubmitButton = document.querySelector(".saveInfoForm");
      formSubmitButton.click();
     }, 10000);
     return () => clearInterval(interval);
   },[])
```

Answer (score 1):

the name of the function is confusing because it triggers on `submit`, not on change.
so you just need to submit the form every 10 sec.

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  formRef.current.submit();
}, 5000);
```

and then `handleDataChange` will be triggered with the event variable. (but still i think its necessary to change its name to `handleDataSubmit`)

Comment: can you explain it more detailed please? Like how should I use ref? I know nothing about Ref

Comment: 'ref' is the way to access elements in react. (instead of `document.querySelector`). you can read the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html